# Symfony authentication always returns "Invalid Credentials"

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I'm trying to implement authentication using Symfony.Unfortunately, I'm getting the error "**Invalid Credentials**" over and over again, no matter what I try.

I've read other articles, but none of them came in handy.What could be the reason for it and how could I manage to fix it?

I tried to modify getUsername() to return the email instead of the username, but it was useless.I checked my registration process, made myself sure whether the hashing is correct, dumped the result of password_verify with the plain password and that one from the database (it was true) and etc.

I believe I've done something wrong.

**security.yml:**

```
security:
    role_hierarchy:

    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\User: bcrypt

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
    providers:
        db_provider:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle\Entity\User
                property: email

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            provider: db_provider
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                username_parameter: _email
                check_path: security_login
                login_path: security_login
                default_target_path: homepage
                always_use_default_target_path: true
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

            logout:
                path: security_logout
                target: security_login

    access_control:
        # this is a catch-all for the admin area
        # addition security lices in the controllers
        # - { path: '^/(%locale%)/admin', roles: ROLE_ADMIN
        # - { path: '^/ucp', roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY] }
```

**login.html.twig**

```
<form name="authenticate" action="{{ path('security_login') }}" method="post" class="loginForm" id="loginForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="_email" value="{{ last_username }}" id="email" placeholder="Имейл адрес"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name=_password" id="password" placeholder="Парола"/>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}">
    <div class="text-center"><button type="submit" id="loginButton">Log in</button></div>
</form>
```

**UserService**

```
class UserService implements UserServiceInterface
{
    private $encryptionService;
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encryptionService,
                                EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->encryptionService = $encryptionService;
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function save(User $user): Response
    {
        $passwordHash = $this->encryptionService->encodePassword($user, $user->getPassword());
        $user->setPassword($passwordHash);

        $this->entityManager->persist($user);
        $this->entityManager->flush();

        return new Response();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your provider said that : **email** is used for authentication but in your login form you are using **_username** for authentification. And then try to inject encoder service through **UserPasswordEncoderInterface** for encoding your password.

Comment: I believe it is pretty the same, but it could be confusing.However, security.yml has been updated and now username_parameter equals _email.That interface, UserPasswordEncoderInterface was also injected, but nothing changed.

Comment: Dumped error in the login form: https://prnt.sc/qitqp2

Answer (score 2):

Oh my gosh, I've solved it...unfortunately it is an embarrassing mistake...I have just missed the very first quote at password name attribute, it was name=_password"

Answer (score 0):

you can use **UserPasswordEncoderInterface** to hash your password clearly like :

```html
.....
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
......

class UserService implements UserServiceInterface
{
    private $userPasswordEncoderInterface;
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(
      UserPasswordEncoderInterface $userPasswordEncoderInterface,
      EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->userPasswordEncoderInterface = $userPasswordEncoderInterface;
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function save(User $user): Response
    {
        $passwordHash = $this->userPasswordEncoderInterface->encodePassword($user, $user->getPassword());
        $user->setPassword($passwordHash);

        $this->entityManager->persist($user);
        $this->entityManager->flush();

        return new Response('password encoded');
    }
}
```

you can see more information in this link : [handle register form](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine/registration_form.html#handling-the-form-submission)

Comment: What would change? Won't it just hash the given password with BCrypt? Are you sure this could be the reason for not letting the user in?

Comment: I think when you hash your password without letting user the result is not the same as if you let the user, can you try and let us feedback

Comment: Well, I tried your advice.That interface that you offered was injected successfully, but there is no change after all.I did a little edit in the login form and security.yml due to the another comment that has been published recently.Article updated.